# how to disable ECHO() for unmatched characters in lex

Tags: lex

I need to disable flex output for unmatched characters. I can't disable this by default ECHO(), can't disable yyout. Any variants?

Comment: like %option nodefault, but need without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creators of lex have provided a much simpler, more maintainable method.  Add the following matching rules at the end of all your other rules:

```
[ \t\n]+          /* do nothing */
.+                /* do nothing */
```

Comment: I think `+` is not correct. `.|[ \t\n]` is okay. Because the pattern matching priority is **longest first**, then top most first. Problems occur when matching part of text in a line because `.+` matches the whole line, and hence the program does nothing. Reference: [StackOverflow: Could I specify pattern match priority in lex code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620978)

Comment: Also, I believe `.|\n` is enough because `.` matches any char but newline. Reference: [Oracle Fundamentals of lex Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-5880/lex-6/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. When you compile with gcc/g++, you have to add the option '-DECHO'. So the 'ECHO' macro will be defined and the program will not print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found. Need to delete ECHO in default rule setup in generated file from lex.

```
case 11:     //For example
YY_RULE_SETUP
#line 68 "flex.l"
ECHO;            //this must be deleted
YY_BREAK
```